# О согласовании со словом "аллюзия"

Tags: согласование

О дополнении к слову "***аллюзия***". Аллюзия к? Аллюзия на? Аллюзия чего-то?

Answer (score 2):

Управление это.

> Нередко возникают сложности с употреблением термина ***аллюзия***, а
> именно с выбором управления. С одной стороны, определение
> ***аллюзии*** как намёка подсказывает пишущему управление с предлогом ***на*** *(аллюзия на что-то)*. С другой стороны, аллюзия как отсылка предполагает, что будет употреблен предлог ***к*** *(аллюзия к
> чему-то)*.

**[источник](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%8F)**

> Специалисты справочно-информационного портала «Русский язык» отмечают,
> что корректным является употребление дательного падежа у зависимого
> слова: *аллюзия к чему-либо*. Однако филологи указывают допустимым и
> новое употребление, возникшее в результате смешения слов «аллюзия» и
> «намек»: *аллюзия на что-либо*.
>
> Таким образом, правильно: кинематограф часто использует аллюзии ***к***
> библейским сюжетам (***на*** библейские сюжеты).

**[источник](https://www.ekburg.ru/news/18/64585-kak-pravilno-allyuziya-na-chto-to-ili-s-chem-to/)**

---

*Чего-то* не рассматривается; это у нас *иллюзия чего-то* место застолбила.